# What are the assignability rules for enum types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, enums

What are the rules for when one can assign to an enum-typed variable in TS?

In particular, the examples below puzzle me:

```
enum A {
  foo = 0,
}

const t2: A.foo = 1729;   // OK by rule 1: A.foo is number-valued
const t1: A = 1729 ;      // OK by rule 2: A has at least one number-valued variant

enum B {
  bar = "hello",
}

const t3: B = 1729;         // Error by rule 2: B has no number-valued variant
const t4: B = "hello";      // Error by rule 3: string isn't as special as number
const t5: B = B.bar;        // OK by rule 3
const t6: "hello" = B.bar;  // OK
```

[playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAglDeAoKUBmB7dUC8UAMANIgL6KIDG6IAzgC5S0BMAXLAHQZa4CMA7IwE4A3CigB6MVADyAaSgAjAJ5QATmAA2wKN1YwOmKAEtqUcBHnAVAWgBuAQ3VhgAEwpU6DHbBzb+AqCKiKBLSckqqGlos3gAWdiZ29Jrx9FRaZhbW9o4uUPYqhnYgtGSgkFAAQgjICnYqPgBEMcDq6ugNRKRuNPS0AMysVTx+gUGiIQCiKiro9eFqmlDRVXEmIFgZlrYOTs55dYXF3R60ACyDjc2t7aPjklMzc8oLWgNQdAUgAOZG1CAA5PR4u8AA7AciFdRQYGbFTHXoAVguuAqbHkdVuQRCsgUz0iUD68IYADZWE0Wm0Gj5UeiVIFsTIgA)

I tried to summarize the behavior I'm seeing with these rules:

1. Any number can be assigned to a variable of dotted enum type when the dotted enum type corresponds to a number-valued enum variant.
2. Any number can be assigned to a variable of enum type exactly when the enum type has at least one number-valued variant.
3. For any non-`number` type, no assignment to an undotted enum type is allowed unless the value was constructed via the enum constructor. (example: Enum.A)

But I'm confused, because the rules don't seem neither sound nor intuitive. Am I understanding correctly? If so, why this behavior?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26362